# iPhone: Local DNS for local domains - cellular data for external addresses

Tags: linux, dns, raspberry-pi, dhcp, powerdns

I recently set up my raspberry pi to as a DNS and DHCP server. Everything is fine - but now I have one remaining problem with iDevices.

The WiFi served by my raspberry pi is local only. There is a web app running on the pi which should be reachable via `http://app.raspberry.localnet` (I did not use .local, since it would conflict with BonJour).

If I connect to the WiFi with my iDevices it recognizes the raspberry as DNS server and the search domain is set to `raspberry.localnet`. The symbol in the status bar states 3G or E depending on reception. Everything looks good. I can reach my app by entering the local IP address, but `http://app.raspberry.localnet` is not resolved.

Any ideas?

Comment: why should app.raspberry.localnet resolve? is there a record for it in your zone?

Comment: Of course there is a record in my zone :) The local dns is configured properly.

Comment: is raspberry receiving queries on udp/53 from your iDevice? And why does it matter whether a symbol in your statusbar says "3G" or "E" when you are connected by WLAN?

Comment: @Bushmills: No - the requests are not received by my raspberry. The symbol matters because I want to retrieve Internet via Edge and 3G. Only local addresses should be resolved and then served via WiFi.

Comment: does raspberry receive queries to nameserver when you first connect to 3G/Edge, and connect to WLAN only after 3G connection was established?

Comment: No - thats the question - why doesn't it?

Comment: what I know as far, I'd say it seems that connecting to WLAN doesn't appear to set to the DHCP provided nameserver, but instead continues to use 3G provider nameserver. But I'm not at the point yet to conclude that with certainty.  Disconnect 3G, then connect to WLAN, see whether you can resolve now.

Comment: Ok - will try that. Is there a way of telling my local DNS server to act as the fallback for the 3g provider name server?

Comment: No, but by telling your local nameserver. But by telling your local DHCP server, or by setting your nameserver statically on client. Effect of DHCP server settings we are currently trying to diagnose, to be used instead, rather than as fallback.

Comment: If I turn off mobile data, the phone is able to resolve the local domain (via mobileTerminal, Safari does not resolve it). When I turn mobile data back on it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. My own answer was wrong. The *.local stuff only works because of mDNS. A feature which is not implemented in android phones. My problem is therefore not solvable. I just have to use IPS ... :/